# Is it possible to deploy a smart contract with the complied abi json file using any flutter web3 package?

Tags: flutter, blockchain, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to develop a Dapp with flutter. There I need to deploy a smart contract for each user to interact with when they sign up for the application. I explored the web3dart library and there were no functions to do that. I there any other library/ method to do that?

Edit: looking for a similar dart method to `myContract.deploy(options)` in web3.js. [reference](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy)

Comment: I would like to recommend you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Jx95kYfYbM&t=604s

Comment: @JohnMelodyMe this video is using truffle migrations to deploy the contracts and just uses the DeployedContract methods to interact with the smart contract functions.
But, my requirement is to deploy a contract upon user sign-up and get the contract address to interact with. If not 2 users use the same contract their data will be mixed up. ( In the video scenario the notes data will be common for both)

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this problem? @Ishad

Comment: @AfaqAhmed No. At that time, `web3dart` didn't support it. Don't know whether it is there.